# Trying to have + on positive and - on negative

Tags: google-sheets-query

This is the code I'm trying to make work...

"=IF (C11>0, "+",OTHERWISE "")

Trying to make it so that if the cell nect to it "C11" is over "0" It gets a "+" sign, otherwise if it's a negative number, Ex "-5", nothing will show up since the sign is negative.

This is my workaround to having to insert the apostrophe in front of the + everytime I want it to show up outside of a formula interaction.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google Maps?

Comment: I had clicked the wrong tag by mistake. I have fixed the error. Please remove negative vote. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should be done with a custom number formatting instead of a formula.

Comment: I look in custon formats, didn't see but never thought to enter my own. Ari Cooper-Davis specified the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select every cell that you want to format (use `ctrl-a` to select all cells).

In the `Format` menu mouse-over `Number`, then mouse-over `More Formats` and select `Custom Number Format`. In the box presented to you type `+0.00;-0.00`.

Press `Apply`. This will format your numbers as desired.

See the [Google Sheets documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for more details.

[image: How to find the custom format settings]
[image]

Comment: :')     Thank you      I feel like my mom when I answer the most basic of cellphone questions and she looks at me like, "If I could only think like that."

Comment: Haha, no need to feel like that, practice makes perfect! ;)